# What is the difference between setting permissions with these two methods?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, php

Method 1: Via apache2.conf (or httpd.conf):

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  AllowOverrides None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Method 2: Chmod in the command-line.

Doesn't both these methods accomplish the same thing?

And another Q if you can answer it, what permissions is the var and www folder usually set to?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 set permission on file system level, so not only for Apache. This is the secure way to set permission on a file.

Method 1 set permission on application layer but Method 2 also apply. If your content can't be read by Apache, then even if Method 1 tells that the client can read the file it will not be able to do it.

So the quick answer is No.
Method 2 will be used to ensure that Apache can read your php file but other users/process can't.
Method 1 will be used to protect page access with a password, etc...

I see you set the PHP tag, take care that Method 1 will never affect what a PHP could read or write. Method 2 as well as PHP configuration will do it.

/var is 755 root/root on my system, www will highly depend on your apache configuration and security you need.